# How to fix the error Error: Default pack is not registered in Nebular

Tags: angular, icons, nebular

What to do if you try load an Nebular page and then this error occurs?

```
Error: Default pack is not registered.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to install the `eva icon pack`:

```sh
npm i --save @nebular/eva-icons
```

and then, import `NbEvaIconsModule` in `AppModule`.

```js
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NbEvaIconsModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And import `NbIconModule` in the module that are you using it.

```js
import { NbIconModule } from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NbIconModule,
  ],
})
export class PageModule { }
```

Restart the app and try again!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install the eva icon pack:

```
npm i --save @nebular/eva-icons
```

Then, import NbEvaIconsModule in AppModule:

```
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';

@NgModule({   imports: [
    // ...
    NbEvaIconsModule,   ]
}) export class AppModule { }
```

And import NbIconModule in the module that are you using it.

```
import { NbIconModule } from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({   imports: [
    // ...
    NbIconModule,   ],
})
export class PageModule { }
```

Restart the app and try again!